# Integrating karma-runner and cucumberjs

Tags: angularjs, cucumber, gruntjs, karma-runner

Has anyone used karma-runner/testacular to execute cucumberjs tests? I suspect that I may have to write an adapter like the Jasmine adapter. Any knowledge on integrating a test library with karam-runner would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently using an adapter I wrote: https://npmjs.org/package/karma-cucumberjs

It's been working fine for me, I'm now using it on a second project. But I am sure there are changes that I could do to it once people start using it and finding things they wish it did. Let me know if there are any problems, you can email me at s9tpepper@apache.org or just use the GitHub issues on the repository. I don't check StackOverflow all that much unless I'm looking for an answer to a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something people want. Jon Perl started [karma-cucumber](https://github.com/jperl/karma-cucumber) recently. It does not include a Karma reporter for Cucumber.js yet but seems to be the plan.

I'll also be looking into this in the near future.

Comment: "Please use s9tpepper/karma-cucumberjs instead.
This project is no longer maintained."